# How to send data from Python to Android App

Tags: php, android, python, json

I'm struggling to send JSON data from Python (in the ip adress of 192.168.2.20/Fetch/Fetch.py as host) to Android. I used to do this in php and it was so easy, all needed to be done was this code:

```
echo json_encode($thedata);
```

But Python seems to be very hard at this and I don't have any idea how to do this, web doesn't seem to be helping at all as most tutorials suggest using frameworks. So how can I include the python file in my Android app and get the JSON, WITHOUT USING FLASK.

Comment: @ShakibKarami The question mentioned by you deals with sending HTTP requests to a server using python. This one is about receiving HTTP requests and sending responses, from server end.

Comment: @Tushar yes thanks I removed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing anything useful, apart from playing around with python as an android app backend, you should start looking for standard python frameworks to handle HTTP server operations, like django or flask.

That being said, there's a small stub that I use to act as a test server for my outgoing requests, which should answer your question. You can set any status code, header or response body by modifying it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Reflects the requests with dummy responses from HTTP methods GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE
# Written by Tushar Dwivedi (2017)

import json
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from optparse import OptionParser

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        request_path = self.path

        print("\n----- Request Start ----->\n")
        print("request_path :", request_path)
        print("self.headers :", self.headers)
        print("<----- Request End -----\n")

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Set-Cookie", "foo=bar")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'hello': 'world', 'received': 'ok'}))

    def do_POST(self):
        request_path = self.path

        # print("\n----- Request Start ----->\n")
        print("request_path : %s", request_path)

        request_headers = self.headers
        content_length = request_headers.getheaders('content-length')
        length = int(content_length[0]) if content_length else 0

        # print("length :", length)

        print("request_headers : %s" % request_headers)
        print("content : %s" % self.rfile.read(length))
        # print("<----- Request End -----\n")

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Set-Cookie", "foo=bar")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps({'hello': 'world', 'received': 'ok'}))

    do_PUT = do_POST
    do_DELETE = do_GET


def main():
    port = 8082
    print('Listening on localhost:%s' % port)
    server = HTTPServer(('', port), RequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.usage = ("Creates an http-server that will echo out any GET or POST parameters, and respond with dummy data\n"
                    "Run:\n\n")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    main()
```

It will do what you are trying to do, out of box. But remember, I just use it as a dummy stub. So, even if you are just exploring, and if there's an Android app involved, and you need to add even 5-6 of `if else`s to the above code to do what you are doing, it's better to do things right from the beginning, to avoid a lot of rework in future. Use a framework capable of handling boilerplate stuff for you.